# Vertically aligning text within an anchor

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to brainstorm on the best way to vertically align text within an anchor and for the method to be cross-browser compatible (ie7+). The best way I have come up with so far is creating a faux element within an anchor, then wrapping the anchor's content in a span (`<ins>` is just an inline element).

```
<a href="#"><ins></ins><span>blah</span></a>
```

Normally, simple padding could accomplish this, but in my test case (http://jsfiddle.net/2jnSP/1/), one of the anchors has multiple lines of text.

So, if you have any better ideas, throw them out there!

Comment: Are the number of lines that the multiline-anchor-element has the same in any number of cases? Also, why use a `<ins>` element, instead of a `<div>` or `<span>`, etc.?

Comment: The goal is for it to be moderately dynamic and vertically center the text regardless of how many lines there are. And you could use a span or any other inline element (semantics) in place of the ins, but it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I have made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Egqjf/1/.

It uses some conditional comments for IE < 8, and `display: table` etc. for modern browsers.

This can be adapted for the elements that you have.

**HTML:**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<div class="wrapper">
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <div class="inner">
    <![endif]-->
        <div class="content">
            <div>blah blah (line 1)</div>
            <div>lorem ipsum (line 2)</div>
        </div>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    </div>
    <![endif]-->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green
}
.content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

---

**Original answer that is probably not useful for this question, but may be useful for others:**

---

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">blah</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider this the optimal way of fixing the problem. There'd be way too much added markup being spitout if you have to do this multiple times per page